# JS как select задать имя не используя option

Tags: javascript, html

Подскажите пожалуйста, как с помощью js для селекта задать имя из блока div или label

На пример:

```html
<label id="nameforselect1">Name Select:</label>
<select id="select1">
  <option value="option1">Option1</option>
  <option value="option1">Option2</option>
  <option value="option1">Option3</option>
  <option value="option1">Option4</option>
</select>
```

Так вот из тэга label нужно взять этот Name Select и положить его в select как название.

Но не используя option disable

Как можно решить данный вопрос, спасибо

Comment: или может добавить в <select атрибут title="MyName -  -  выводить его ?

Answer (score -1):

Все решено.

Многими любимый Bootstrap все сделал:
https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/examples/#placeholder